# SDL Jpeg dll not finding jpeg_calc_output_dimensions?

Tags: dll, sdl, jpeg, sdl-image

I'm trying to use a 64-bit application that uses SDL (and SDL Image in particular) (on Windows).  The application runs, but I didn't have a 64-bit jpeg loader.  SDL-Image expects a jpeg.dll, but the package I got off the IJG Website (http://www.ijg.org/) builds into a static lib.  I changed the configuration properties to build into a .dll, but it's not finding the jpeg_calc_output_dimensions function. I ran dumpbin on the .dll, and it is not exporting any symbols.  I'm going to try adding some exports to the source and rebuilding, but I'm hesitant to edit such an extensively used package.

Has anyone been in a similar situation and found a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I manged to make the code export all the symbols and then I just had to swap the included jpeg headers into the ones in SDL_Image/graphics, and it worked.